# Wrong behavior with ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Visible value

Tags: c#, macros, powerpoint-2010

I have strange behavior with value  `ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Visible`.
I have few paragraphs with bullets (bullets looks like rectangles). So, when I am calling `TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Visible = msoFalse;` for all bullets, they becomes hidden, but when I try to make some bullet visible `TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Visible = msoTrue;` it becomes visible, with wrong view, in my case bullet looks like number `1.` 
For me it look like bug in PP2010, if we set up `Bullet.Visible` to false it resets bullet settings.

Answer (score 1):

I think the property you want is:

```
TextFrame2.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Bullet.Type = ppBulletUnnumbered;
```

Otherwise it seems that Powerpoint unintuitive defaults bullets to numbers.